# Stuck writing to JCSP channel

Tags: java, channel

I have this really simple **JCSP**(Java Communicating Sequential Processes) code sample in which I'm trying to write an integer to a *One2OneInt* channel and then read it.

```
package jcsp;
import org.jcsp.lang.*;

public class JCSP {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    One2OneChannelInt chan = Channel.one2oneInt();
    chan.out().write(5);

    System.out.println("Written...");

    System.out.println(chan.in().read());
    }
}
```

It seems that value never gets written on the channel and program just keeps running. **"Written..."** is never printed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I learned about `BlockingQueue` and its implementation `SynchronousQueue`. As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html), `SynchronousQueue` works in similar way  in which `CSP Channels` work. This helped me realize what was wrong with my code. Simply put, you can't `write` and `read` from channel in same process. `Channel` is way for **processes** to communicate.

Similarly to `SynchronousQueue's` `put()` which will wait for other process to call `take()`, `CSP Channel's` `write()` which will wait for corresponding `read()` to be called. The difference is that `CSP Channels` have objects `ChannelOutput` and `ChannelInput` through which objects are written and red. Conversely, you can call `put` and `take` directly on instance of `SynchronousQueue`. Personally, I find `SynchronousQueue` much easier to understand, which probably relates to `JCSP` not being very popular.

Still, if you're interested how I made the above code work in JCSP, here it is:

```
public static class Process1 implements CSProcess {

    private ChannelOutputInt output;

    public Process1(ChannelOutputInt out) {
        output = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Written...");
            output.write(5);
        }
        output.write(-1);
    }

}

public static class Process2 implements CSProcess {

    private ChannelInputInt input;

    public Process2(ChannelInputInt in) {
        input = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int x = 0;
        while ((x = input.read()) > 0) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    One2OneChannelInt chan = Channel.one2oneInt();

    Process1 process1 = new Process1(chan.out());
    Process2 process2 = new Process2(chan.in());

    Parallel parallel = new Parallel();

    parallel.addProcess(process1);
    parallel.addProcess(process2);
    parallel.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the channel is unbuffered, so your `write()` call will block until another process reads from the channel.  As soon as another process calls `read()`, **'Written...'** will be printed out.

A `BlockingQueue` with a capacity of 0 behaves similarly to a JCSP channel